# Why does this automatic night light advertise money savings?

Tags: electricity

I just bought a night light to light the hallway since it receives no outside light. The one I bought advertises that it saves money because it turns on only during the night or (dark hours). I did the calculations and I am confused as to why it is even advertised because I did the calculations to find the cost per month to run it and as it turns out the money savings are absolutely miniscule.

The power information on the night light is 120v, 60hz, and 0.15w.

To find the cost to run it per month:

0.15w * 1kw/1000w * 24 hours * 30 days = 0.108 kwh per month.

At a cost of 9 cents per kwh, the total cost comes to less than 1 cent per month. The fact that the night light is automatic does not make a big difference on my wallet--why with a dollar I could run it for 8.3 years. Am I missing something or is this just an example of advertising?

Comment: Well, try to see it from this angle. Suppose it runs for one half of the time of an always lit lamp. You, as a single user, save 0.65 kWh per year. If 1 billion users in the world used this light instead of an always lit one, they would contribute to saving 0.65 TWh per year. Also, you have to compute the cost of delivering energy to your home which can even be more of what the lamp consume (but has to be generated).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about issues in advertising and not physics.

Comment: @KyleKanos I was just wondering if I was missing something in the Physics equations because the answer seemed a little odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pure marketing, but not a lie... 0.036cents/mo is less than 0.108 cents/mo.

Comment: To put it in other terms, a 67% savings!

Comment: I was just wondering if I was missing something. It seemed trivial to advertise for such a small savings.